# A bug disappears when I print something in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I know the title is not very clear, but I don't know what else I can say.

I have a player attacking, and when he is done attacking, I start a timer for 1 second, so we have to wait one second before attacking again. It wasn't working (we could attack only once) and I didn't know why, so I added `print(self.between_two_attacks())`and everything worked fine, I could attack, wait one second and attack again.

Here is the program, I don't know if it is enough because I have no idea where the bug comes from.

```
def between_two_attacks(self):
    if self.after_attack_max == 0:
        self.after_attack_max = pg.time.get_ticks() + 1000
        print("set timer")
    else:
        after_attack = pg.time.get_ticks()
        print("start timer")
        if after_attack >= self.after_attack_max:
            print("can attack again")
            self.can_attack = True
            self.after_attack_max = 0

def draw(self, win):
    print(self.between_two_attacks())
    if (self.attackcount + 1) >= 5:
        self.attackcount = 0
        self.between_two_attacks()
        self.action = STAND_UP
        self.arme = LIGHTSABER_OUT
        self.stops_attacking = True
        self.can_attack = False
    if self.action == ATTACKING:
        win.blit...

Run = True
While Run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE and player.can_attack == True:
                player.action = ATTACKING
```

If anything isn't clear in this part of the program, just tell me and I'll try to explain. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: where do you call your function between_two_attacks(self) except print(self.between_two_attacks())?

Comment: I only call it in the print and three lines under, in the draw function

Comment: and why you call it in print ?

Comment: because it wasn't working, and I wanting to see what it would write in the python shell

Comment: Call it without print at the same place and do not change anything else. Tell us what happens.

Comment: well that's what I did first, and the result is explain in my question

Comment: Oh, ok, I understood that you added the whole line `print(self.between_two_attacks())` Also can you provide the full code via pasteubuntu or similar, this looks like a difficult one to debug

Comment: Maybe what I wrote isn't clear. I had the code I posted, but without the line ```print(self.between_two_attacks())```. I wanted to see where there was a problem, so I printed this

Comment: Well, that is what I meant, I will describe in an answer what I think happens here.

Answer (score 2):

The method `between_two_attacks` has to be invoked, before the state of `self.can_attack` is retrieved. `self.can_attack` is set in `between_two_attacks`. If the method is not called, the `self.can_attack` will never become `True`.
When you do `print(self.between_two_attacks())`, the `self.between_two_attacks()` is called.

Furthermore, the method can be simplified:

`self.can_attack` has to be set if `self.after_attack_max == 0` or if the current time is greater than `self.after_attack_max`.
If `self.can_attack` is set then compute the restart the timer. If it is not set then it has to be evaluated. Initially `self.after_attack_max` is 0. If the current time is greater than `self.after_attack_max`, attacks have to be allowed and the timer has to be started again:

```py
def between_two_attacks(self):

    current_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
    if self.can_attack:
        self.after_attack_max = current_time + 1000

    elif current_time > self.after_attack_max:
        self.can_attack = True
        self.after_attack_max = current_time + 1000
```

Note, `self.after_attack_max` is only set in `between_two_attacks`, do not reset it anywhere else.

Comment: I have not seen that you posted before me, I would not do it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Rabbid76, I’ll test that and see if it works !

Comment: @kaktus_car Why are you apologizing? Of course you are allowed to post a different answer!

Comment: @Rabbid76 I know but it  essentially says the same thing and you explained in more detail and better I generalized it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I changed my function and wrote your answer, but then I removed the line « print(self.between_two_attacks()) », and it bugs again, I attack once and then I can hit the space key as many time as I want, it won’t do anything. Is there something I didn’t understand from your answer ?

Comment: @bappi Then you have to show more code. It is impossible to answer the question without to see the code that invokes `between_two_attacks`. All what we are doing here is to guess.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I know, but the code is mainly not in English (the name of the variables and is 1400 lines long, so I don’t know what part to show

Comment: @bappi Where do you call `self.between_two_attacks()` in your code? Do you call it in the KEYDOWN event, when space is pressed?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I define it in the player class and call it once the attacking animation is done, that’s all. I will update my question so you have more things

Comment: @bappi You have to call it when SPACE is pressed. How do you think that `self.can_attack` will get `True`, when `self.between_two_attacks()` is never called?

Comment: @Rabbid76 so the timer will start as the same time as the attacking action, and will continue after attacking is done ?

Comment: @b The timer is restarted when `self.can_attack` is `False` and `self.between_two_attacks()` is called. When space is pressed, the call `self.between_two_attacks()`. If `self.can_attack` is `True`, then do the attack and set  `self.can_attack = False` again.

Comment: @Rabbid76 it is still not working, but I think I’ll give up, it must be hard for you as you can’t see the whole code, and I don’t want to copy paste 1400 lines here

Answer (score 0):

When you print `self.between_two_attacks()` the `self` function gets called and executed. Now, if you added the whole line it means that this function was not executed at this point before and now it is, so if you remove print and left only function at the same location you should get the same behaviour.
I do not know if I manage to explain my thought so here as a quick example:

```
x = 5

def change_x():
    global x
    x+=10

print(x)

print(change_x())

print(x)
```

if you remove `print()` you will get same result.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, if it is working with the print, it will work without ? Because when I saw it was working with the print, I removed the line and it didn’t work

Comment: Exactly, just remove `print()` leave `self.between_two_attacks()`. Look at the @Rabbid76 answer, it is more detail and better explained.